# React event being updated onChange

Tags: javascript, reactjs

> Disclaimer: to quickly see the issue, please [see this pen](http://codepen.io/nescalante/pen/pEakbE) and type something there.

#### The implementation

I have this JSX code for my render method:

```
<input
  value={this.state.value}
  onChange={this.handleChange}
/>
```

And then this is my `handleChange` method:

```
handleChange(e) {
  const { onChange } = this.props;

  this.setState({
    value: e.target.value,
  }, () => {
    onChange({ value: e.target.value });
  });
}
```

#### The issue

The thing is that on the `handleChange` method, when setting the state, `e.target` contains the input element, but on the callback for the `setState` method, `e.target` is null (so the `onChange` method is not being called).

#### Yes, it has an obvious workaround

Of course that if I set a var to store the target before firing `setState`, I can use that target on the callback. But I would like to understand why is that `e` being updated (and the target being removed from there), if this is just an issue or its just the way that it should work. Again, [this pen](http://codepen.io/nescalante/pen/pEakbE) will show the issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're running into consequences of the fact that [what React passes you are actually synthetic events, that are *recycled*](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/events.html). Quoting the docs:

> The SyntheticEvent is pooled. This means that the SyntheticEvent
>   object will be reused and all properties will be nullified after the
>   event callback has been invoked.

The workaround is to store the target beforehand, or to do as the docs say, and call `event.persist()`

Answer (score 1):

React does a garbage handling of sorts with events, so it will actually remove that event before the callback has taken place.

You can do `e.persist()` and it will work just fine, that makes sure the event hangs around and doesn't get wiped away.